How to add itemscope into html tag using function.php
How to add itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" to html tag using function.php
add_filter( 'nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_menu_attributes', 10, 3 );

function jrod_add_html_manifest( $output ) {

    $output .= ' itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage"';

    return $output;
}


What is add_filter()? If this is part of a framework, please add the appropriate tag.

your filter its not loading the function you have provided.
Here is working solution
function add_itemscope_itemtype_filter( $atts, $item, $args ) {
    $atts['itemscope itemtype'] = 'http://schema.org/WebPage';
    return $atts;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_itemscope_itemtype_filter', 3, 10);

